# Mac how to create environment variables

Tags: macos, operating-system, environment-variables

How can I create environment variables on Mac to protect passwords and access keys in my projects? I have tried using

```
touch .profile
nano .profile
```

Then entering my variables, e.g.

```
export MY_PASS='abcdefg'
```

But after saving this, it does not show up when I use the command

```
env
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Did you start a new terminal and verify that they're still not there?

Comment: Yeah, I quit the terminal and restarted it but they don't show. I'm making sure to save and close it first, so I don't know where I'm going wrong.